# Client server multiway chat

Tags: c, sockets, serversocket

I'm able to send message from client and from server but to continuously send messages I put my code in an infinite loop but after one write and read It stops working I don't get any error but when I type something in the client terminal It doesn't send anything to the server so what should I do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<error.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#define PORTNO 10200
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int sockfd,newsockfd,portno,clilen,n=1;

    char buf[256]=" ",ch[256]=" ";

    struct sockaddr_in seraddr,cliaddr;

    int i,value;

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(sockfd==-1)
    {
        perror("Socket Error"); 
    }   
    seraddr.sin_family=AF_INET;

    seraddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.86.4.132");

    seraddr.sin_port=htons(10200);

    bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&seraddr,sizeof(seraddr));

    listen(sockfd,1);

    clilen=sizeof(clilen);

    newsockfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&clilen);
        if(newsockfd==-1)
    {
        perror("NEW SOCKET ERROR"); 
    }
    n=read(newsockfd,buf,sizeof(buf));
    if(n==-1)
    {
        perror("READ ERROR");   
    }
    if(strcmp(buf,"QUIT")==0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }    
    printf("CLIENT:");  
    puts(buf);

    printf("\n ENTER STRING \t");
    gets(ch);

    ch[strlen(ch)]='\0';
    strcpy(buf,ch);
    write(newsockfd,buf,strlen(ch));
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

and THIS is my client code

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<error.h>
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
    int len,result,sockfd,n=1;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    char ch[256]=" ",buf[256]=" ";
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sockfd==-1)
    {
        perror("Socket Error"); 
    }       
    address.sin_family=AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.86.4.132");
    address.sin_port=htons(10200);
    len=sizeof(address);

    result=connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&address,len);
    if(result==-1)
    {
        perror("\n CLIENT ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i=0;        
    printf("\n ENTER STRING \t");
    gets(ch);       
    ch[strlen(ch)]='\0';
    write(sockfd,ch,strlen(ch));
    printf("STRING:");

        n=read(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf));
        if(n==-1)
        {
            perror("Read Error");
        }
        puts(buf);  
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: 'ch[strlen(ch)]='\0';' this is either useless or pointless, depending on whether the char array is alrady NUL-terminated or not.

Comment: 'puts(buf);' call requiring a NUL-terminated string with a char array that is not guaranteed NUL-terminated.